# How to add schedule for steps with different time in sql server Jobs

Tags: sql-server-2008

In sql server job have two steps and two schedules with different time and date. Now i want to setup one step to one schedule and another step to another schedule.

Please let me know the process of setup.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't believe there is any way to schedule a *step*.  The schedule applies to the *job*...  In other words, you need to break your job with two steps into two jobs with one step each in order to schedule them for different times.

Comment: You're correct. You could insert a SQL step with a `WAITFOR` that makes the whole job wait until a certain time, but your job would be in a running state the whole time

Comment: Could one of you edit this answer with some sketch of the steps you're talking about.  It's hard to imagine right now.  thank you

Answer (score 3):

Part 1 is @Clay's response 
If you still need a cheat code then

- Schedule the job for a certain time and in your steps check for the server time and then decide if you want to execute the step or not for e.g. a stored proc could be a good place to check.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! For an hourly schedule, add this to the step to only run before 8am and after 5pm `IF NOT (select datepart(hour, getdate())) between 8 and 17 /* sql for step */`